# Which is best practice? Identity type or setting a dynamic property runtime?

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

While designing a class I assumed that having an `$id` property will make that class `Entity` rather than  a value object.

I also have a `toArray()` method which converts the object to associative array and that response is send to post and patch api's.

Now I have the following questions:

`POST` works,
since I’m not sending the `id` in the body. But for `PATCH` is it fine if I set the property dynamically after object creation? For Ex:

```
$redCircle = new Circle(“red”);
$redCircle->id = 10;
$api->patch($redCircle->toArray());
```

Comment: Please, make your question clearer. I recommend you to read this article: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Your point of view is very technical, as opposed to DDD.

You should design your Aggregates and nested Entities according to the business rules (the invariants).

> While designing a class I assumed that having an $id property will make that class Entity rather than a value object.

This is not true. There are cases when a local Value object (that comes from a remote Aggregate, in another Bounded context) needs an ID property in order to be kept up-to-date (i.e. by background tasks). The Anti-corruption layer would need this property, so the reasons are pure technical.

> POST works, since I’m not sending the id in the body. But for PATCH is it fine if I set the property dynamically after object creation?

Again, this is not a DDD view of the problem. In DDD, an Aggregate execute commands: one does not simply update its internal state directly; this would break its encapsulation.

But to answer your question, considering that you have a [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) app: In order to mutate parts of an Entity you would need to load it from the [Repository](https://pehapkari.cz/blog/2018/02/28/domain-driven-design-repository/) before mutation. The Repository would set the ID along with the other properties.

One of the best ways to locate entities is to use a [RESTful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming) API, so the client would not need to construct the URLs for the PATCH operation.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But I have a follow-up question. What if the data coming from form is converted to a domain object and that domain object is passed to API body in some format. And the Id on the object is generated by the database table.

Comment: @SaiVallamsetti then the Repository would populate the ID accordingly